# EMR Job Long Running Notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

Consider we have around 30 EMR Jobs runs in 5:30 AM PST to 10:30 PST.
We have **S3 Buckets** and we use to receive flat files in S3 bucket and through lambda functions, received files will be copied to other target paths.
We have dynamo DB tables for data processing once data gets received in target path.
Now the problem area is since we have multiple dependencies & parallel execution, sometimes job gets failed due to memory issue as well as sometimes take more time to get completed.
Sometimes it will run for 4 or 5 hours, and finally it will get terminated with memory or any other issues like Subnet not available or EC2 issue. So we dont want to wait till that long time.
Eg: Job_A process some 1st to 4th files and Job_B processes from 5th to 10th files. Like that it goes.
Here Job_B has dependency with Job_A with 3rd file. So, Job_B will wait until Job_A gets completed. Like this dependency we have in our process.
I would like to get notification from EMR Jobs like below,
Eg: Average Running time for Job_A is 1 hour, but it is running for more than 1 hour and in this case I need to **get notified** by email or any other way. 
How to achieve it? Please help or advise anyone.
Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeatedly call the list of steps by using lambda and aws sdk, e.g. boto3 and check the start date. When it is 1 hour behind, then you can trigger some notification like Amazon SES. See the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.list_steps).

For example, you can call the `list_steps` for the running steps only.

```
response = client.list_steps(
    ClusterId='string',
    StepStates=['RUNNING']
)
```

Then it will give you below response.

```
{
    'Steps': [
        {
            ...

            'Status': {

                ...

                'Timeline': {
                    'CreationDateTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
                    'StartDateTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
                    'EndDateTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
                }
            }
        },
    ],
    ...
}
```